# Не получается напечатать код страницы с помощью requests

Tags: python, парсер, requests

```
import requests

URL = "https://megamarket.ru/"
r = requests.get(URL).text
print(r)
```

Не получается получить код страницы мегамаркета.Если запустить этот код, то вместо кода страницы выведется что то не понятное(во всяком случае для меня). Я подозреваю, что мегамаркету не нравится мой запрос и он его не пропускает. Подскажите, как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Ну покажи непонятное-то. Мне показывает код.

Comment: я не знаю как вставить сюда все что выводит. Сначала идет css почему то, а потом какие то функции по типу                                                                                                                        
  function get_cookie_spsc() {
  // console.time("decrypt");
  const ret = get_cookie_spsc_uncrypted_part() + get_cookie_spsc_encrypted_part();
  // console.timeEnd("decrypt");
  return "oirutpspsc=" + ret;
}
function get_options() {
  return JSON.parse('{"is_captcha":false}');

Comment: ну, а разве это не код? очень даже код. Видимо у вас какое то свое понимание слова "код", о котором мы не догадываемся

Comment: В этом коде нет ни одного заголовка, ни одного div, p итд. Я не могу найти в этом коде ничего из того, что есть на странице. Попробуйте запустить его и найти хотя бы один товар в html коде.

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что в html коде должны быть товары. Так сайты в наше время не строят (тем более крупные) Современные сайты - это приложения написанные на javascript, которые подтягивают свое наполнение (сами данные, не разметку) по API и потом сами строят html на ходу

Comment: Ну и тот кусок "не кода" возможно код для защиты от скачивания и парсинга

Comment: Мне выводит самый обычный код, начинается <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  И заканчивается 
  </script>
</body>
</html> А у вас, похоже, открывается сначала капча, а не сама страница.